# Очередь с приоритетами на основе упорядоченного массива

Tags: c++, алгоритм

> Напишите реализацию основного интерфейса очереди по приоритетам, который использует упорядоченный массив в качестве базовой структуры данных.

Если я пытался добавлять новые элементы в очередь, в которой уже есть один и только один элемент, то цикл с условием не выполнялся, потому что условие цикла выглядело как 1 < 1. Добавил еще один if, и теперь добавление возрастающей последовательности работает правильно.

PS. Мне объяснили, что поддерживать массив отсортированным нужно по тому же принципу, по которому работает сортировка вставками. Можете описать словами этот алгоритм поддержания упорядоченности?

```
#include <iostream>

class Item{
private:
    int key;
    int data;
public:
    Item(): data(0), key(0){}
    Item(int data, int key): data(data), key(key){}
    void print(){
        std::cout << "data: " << data << ", key " << key << std::endl;
    }
    bool operator <(const Item &item){ return key < item.key; }
    bool operator >(const Item &item){ return key > item.key; }
};

template<class Item>
class PQ{
private:
    Item *pq;   /*Массив элементов*/
    int n;      /*Текущее оличество элементов в очереди*/
public:
    PQ(int max){
        pq = new Item[max];
        n = 0;
    }

    int empty() const{ return n == 0; }

    void insert(Item item){
        int pos = 0;        /*Позиция для вставки*/
        int max = 0;    /*Максимальный элемент в очереди*/

        if(n == 0)  /*Если в очереди еще нет элементов*/
            pos = 0;
        else if(n == 1)
            pos = 1;
        else
            for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
                if(pq[i] > pq[max])
                    max = i;

        if(max != 0) pos = max + 1;
        pq[pos] = item;
        n++;
        //pq[n++] = item;
    }

    Item getmax(){
        int max = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if(pq[max] < pq[i])
                max = i;
        std::swap(pq[max], pq[n-1]);
        return pq[--n];
    }

    Item getmin(){
        int min = 0;

        for(int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            if(pq[min] > pq[i])
                min = i;
        std::swap(pq[min], pq[n-1]);
        return pq[--n];
    }

    void show(){
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            pq[i].print();
    }
};

int main(){
    int p;;
    PQ<Item> pq(50);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        pq.insert(Item(7, i));

    pq.show();

    std::cout << "max: ";
    pq.getmax().print();
    std::cout << "max: ";
    pq.getmax().print();
    std::cout << "min: ";
    pq.getmin().print();
    std::cout << "min: ";
    pq.getmin().print();

    std::cin >> p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Мои попытки. Вроде все верно. Да? https://ideone.com/HAz2LX

Comment: Не понял. Код по ссылке - не тот, что вы запостили здесь. Вставку вы исправили (я не проверял), но вопиющая бессмысленность методов `getmax` и `getmin` по-прежнему бросается в глаза.

Comment: @typemoon Я думаю, что если у вас указан массив в качестве базовой структуры, то в классе очереди должен быть определен именно массив, и размер массива должен быть шаблонным параметром класса. Также если в задании говорится об "основном интерфейсе" очереди с приоритетами, то наверное этот основной интерфейс должен быть уже определен где-то в предыдущем материале перед заданием. Из вашего вопроса неясно, что входит в этот основной интерфейс.

Answer (score 1):

- Написана ерунда с точки зрения выполнения массы "бессмысленной работы". Весь смысл поддержания массива в упорядоченном состоянии как раз и состоит в том, чтобы функции `getmax` и `getmin` отрабатывали *мгновенно*, возвращая либо первый, либо последний элемент массива.

  А когда эти функции вдруг начинают тупо с нуля линейным поиском искать максимальный или минимальный элемент, то становится видно, что автор кода не понимал что и зачем делает.
- Вставка реализована неправильно. Т.е. вообще непонятно, что написано. При вставке надо искать позицию для нового элемента в существующем отсортированном массиве. Данная реализация зачем-то ищет позицию существующего максимального элемента в массиве и пытается сразу что-то писать после него (???)

  В любом случае, если вставка делается в начало или середину массива, то, понятное дело, перед вставкой надо отодвинуть существующий элементы массива вправо. Ничего подобного я в коде не вижу.
- Const-correctness хромает. Почему операторы `<` и `>` не `const`? (Хватило бы, кстати, и одного). Отсутствует проверка на вылет за пределы выделенной памяти.

Comment: AnT, просто сопоставьте с [предыдущим вопросом того же автора](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439598)

Comment: Насчет ненужности линейного поиска в getmax и getmin согласен, но это исходный вариант, я их сделал такими до того, как добавил поддержание упорядоченности массива. Кроме того, свапом портится весь порядок, но цель была просто добавить упорядоченность, а потом думать про все остальное. Никто не заметил, что функция show лишает код общности и заставляет работать только с одним типом данных. Лучше использовать << и переопределить его в Item. Также там есть переполнение буффера, которое закончится UB'ом, и отсутствие конструктора копирования и = у PQ, поэтому код a=b (a, b - очереди)приведет к UB